# Inductive proof for gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

Proof that $(\forall n \in \Bbb N)[\gcd(n,(25n+1)^3)=1]$

By the inductive method:
$p(n):\gcd(n,(25n+1)^3)=1$

- $p(1): \gcd(1,26^3)=1 \implies p(n)\equiv \text{True}$
- $p(n): $I assume that $p(n)\equiv \text{True}$, i.e, I'll take the expression $gcd(n,(25n+1)^3)=1$ as my inductive hypothesis.
- $p(n+1): \gcd(n,(25n+1)^3)=\gcd(n,25^3n^3+3\times 25^2n^2+3\times25+1)=\gcd(n, 15625n^3+1875n^2+76) ...$

But, I can't take it from here.

I know that: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b+a\times k)$ with $k\in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Is it told you to prove it by induction? Or it was your last idea to try?

Comment: Only by induction!

Comment: Doing this by induction is really more work than necessary and obscures the issue. Expand $(25n+1)^3 = n t + 1$.

Comment: Double-check you source, because it would be *very strange* for such an exercise to require a proof by *induction* on $n.$

Comment: This exercise must be proven using mathematical induction; I know that it's strange, but (...)

Comment: Well if you are going to use induction, you should start by writing p(n+1) correctly.

Comment: What's the problem with $p(n+1)$?

Comment: @Tomi: $p(n+1)$ is $$\gcd\left(n+1,\big(25(n+1)+1\big)^3\right)=1\;,$$ obtained by substituting $n+1$ for $n$ in $p(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this by induction without ever using the induction hypothesis. Your $p(n+1)$ (which you have to show) reads $\gcd(n+1,(25(n+1)+1)^3)=1$. Calling $m=n+1$ for simplicity, the left hand side becomes $\gcd(m,(25m+1)^3)$, and since $(25m+1)^3\equiv 1^3=1\pmod m$, the rule $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,y\bmod x)$ gives you $\gcd(m,(25m+1)^3)=\gcd(m,1)=1$ as desired.

Alternatively, if you should be forced to actually use your induction hypothesis, you might use the freedom to perform induction on something other than $n$. Instead, you can first generalise your statement to $\forall k\in\Bbb N:\forall n\in\Bbb N:\gcd(n,(25n+1)^k)$, and now prove this by induction on $k$. This can be done using $\gcd(n,(25n+1)^{k+1})=\gcd(n,(25n+1)^k)$, which follows from
$$(25n+1)^{k+1}=(25n+1)(25n+1)^k\equiv1(25n+1)^k=(25n+1)^k\pmod n.$$ Don't forget to
specialise to $k=3$ afterwards.

Moral: one who poses silly questions should expect silly answers.