# Prove $(\forall n \in \Bbb N)[\gcd\left(n,(16n+1)^3\right)=1]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-verification, divisibility

Prove $(\forall n \in \Bbb N)[\gcd(n,(16n+1)^3)=1]$

Knowing that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b+a\times k)$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$

$$\gcd\left(n,(16n+1)^3\right)=\gcd\left((16n+1)^3,n\right)=d$$
$$\gcd\left(n,(16n+1)^3\right)=d \implies d|n \land d |(16n+1)^3 \implies d | n+(16n+1)^3$$
$$d|1\times (16n+1)^3 + (-1)\times \left( n+(16n+1)^3 \right )$$
$$d|(-1)\times n\implies d|(-1) \lor d|n$$
$$d|(-1)\implies d=(-1)\times 1\implies d|1$$
Finally $\gcd \left( n,(16n+1)^3 \right ) =1, \forall n \in \Bbb Z$

My question is:

> This is well done? if not, could someone help me to find another way
>   to prove this?

Regards!

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611191/inductive-proof-for-gcd

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to know is :

$(16n+1)^3=4096n^3+768n^2+48n+1$

suppose $p$ is a prime dividing $n$ then..... ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You conclude at the end that $d|(-1)$ **or** $d|n$, but you ignore the possibility $d|n$.

Here is another way of looking at it.  If $d|(16n+1)^3$ and $d>1$, then $d$ has a prime factor $p$, and we must have $p|(16n+1)$.  So if $\gcd(n, (16n+1)^3) > 1$, then $e=\gcd(n, 16n+1) >1$.  But $e|[(16n+1) - 16\cdot(n)]$; that is, $e|1$.  So this is impossible and $\gcd(n, (16n+1)^3) = 1$.

Comment: But, if $d|(-1) \lor d | n \implies d|1 \lor d |1 \times n$ then $d|1$, not yet?

Comment: No.  For instance, it is true that $2|(-1)$ or $2|4$, but certainly $2\nmid 1$.

Comment: Then, Can I use the Hypothesis and say: "By hypothesis, $\gcd(a,b)=1 \implies d|1 \land d=1$"?
Sorry for the incistence, but I want some proof like that.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?  You don't have any *hypothesis* that two numbers in your problem are relatively prime...

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's true; I'm very confused. Thanks anyway!